# How many sets of armor does Erza have?

Tags: fairy-tail

I have been wondering this whole time since I recently started watching Fairy Tail.

How many sets of armor does Erza have and how can she make new ones?

Comment: i reworded your question cause it kinda sound the same as *"how many money do i have"*, though it was a toss up between **how much armor** and **how many sets of armor** and i went with the later because i don't think Erza switches the top and bottom half around seperatly. if i've changed the meaning to your question please revise my edit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was never mentioned exactly how many equipment she has, but according to [Fairy Tail Wiki](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/):

> Erza owns over 100 different types of armor, and over 200
> different types of weapons.

A part of this equipment is stored in other dimension and the other part is placed at her room, as mentioned in the section [The Knight](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/The_Knight) (name of Erza's requip skill):

> This Magic allows the user to store weapons and armors in pocket
> dimensions and summon them during battle.
> [...]
>
> there is a limit to how much the pocket dimension can store, and as a
> result, she leaves some of her armors in her room in Fairy Hills.

And answering your second question, Erza is an user of requip magic, in other words, she can summon weapons and armors during the battles, but she does not create them.

[Here](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/Erza_Scarlet#cite_ref-Volume_9.2C_Q.26A_48-0) or [here](http://fairytail.wikia.com/wiki/The_Knight) you can see the list of all weapons and armors that already appeared in the manga/anime.

Comment: i think you can say Erza **is** a user or requip magic as i'm it's explained at the start that's exactly what she's doing (unless there some ambiguity added later on)

Comment: Ow, so Erza can requip multiple weapons despite having to requip an armor? Like for example requip an armor then she can requip 1 or more weapons as well?

Comment: Yes. It's possible to equip only an armor or only a weapon, it's even possible to combine different weapons and armors from different known sets, according to the wiki I refered.

Comment: @Rikkin Ow, thanks for the info somehow it reminds me of Monster Hunter. XD